# ActiveMQ 5.15 HTTP ERROR: 503

Tags: activemq-classic

Run environment ：linux （CentOS 7）, JDK 1.8, & ActiveMQ 5.15

I started Activemq then visit the management page with Chrome，when I try to log in with the default username & password I get the following error;

> HTTP ERROR: 503
>
> Problem accessing /admin/. Reason:
>
> Service Unavailable Powered by Jetty://

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you please provide the output from the `activemq.log` file which should be inside the run environment - It should give some useful error messages. Please edit your question using the link underneath and add the info.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error.  It turns out that I had run it as root user originally, then later I stopped it and ran it as a non-root user.  Certain data files that had been created and owned by the original root instance were not accessible to the non-root user.

Check the ownership of the files, and change them if necessary to match the user that the broker is running as.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
Maybe something went wrong the extraction of the package.

I downloaded this:

```
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/5.15.0/apache-activemq-5.15.0-bin.tar.gz
```

and extracted it with:

```
sudo tar -zxvf apache-activemq-5.15.0-bin.tar.gz -C /opt
```

then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

I start with the activemq in Ubuntu Repo, but then later change to binary package from official website.

In my case, the repo version left an /etc/default/activemq config file, which runs activemq with user "activemq". It turns out in previous experiments, I did not kill the old processes running under "activemq" when I start activemq under my own user name. There are two activemq processes running under different user names, and when connecting to admin console, I have a 503.

I delete the /etc/default/activemq file, and kill all activemq processes running under "activemq", then restart activemq with my user name, the 503 is gone.